# ¿Como puedo saber la diferencia en año, mes y dia entre dos fechas dadas usando una función en PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql

Necesito saber la diferencia en años, meses, y días entre dos fecha para luego retornar en una función en mi reporte.

Cree la siguiente función pero me retorna únicamente la diferencia en días pero con el símbolo negativo.

De antemano, les agradezco por su atención.

```
function CF_ANTIGUEDADFormula return VARCHAR is
   V_RETORNO VARCHAR2(1000);
begin
   //:FECHA_ALTA ES LA FECHA QUE ESTOY OBTENIENDO DE LA BASE DE DATOS
   V_RETORNO := TO_DATE(:FECHA_ALTA,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')-TRUNC(SYSDATE);

RETURN V_RETORNO;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta función es la que utilizo para hacer algo similar a lo que necesitas. 
puedes modificar la salida a como la necesitas.

```
create or replace FUNCTION DIFERENCIA_2_FECHAS
      -- retorna:  AAA.MMDD en decimal (16,4)
    (
     fch_actual     DATE,
     fch_anterior DATE
    )  RETURN NUMBER
    AS     
      p_anios   INTEGER;
      p_meses  INTEGER;
      p_dias   INTEGER; 

  BEGIN

     IF (fch_actual IS NULL) OR (fch_anterior IS NULL) THEN
         RETURN NULL;
     END IF;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,'' ';

    p_anios  := (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fch_actual)  - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fch_anterior));
    p_meses := (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM fch_actual) - EXTRACT(MONTH FROM fch_anterior));
    p_dias  := (EXTRACT(DAY FROM fch_actual)   - EXTRACT(DAY FROM fch_anterior));

     IF p_anios < 0 THEN
         RETURN DIFERENCIA_2_FECHAS( fch_anterior, fch_actual);   
     ELSIF  p_anios = 0 THEN 
         IF  p_meses < 0 THEN   
             RETURN DIFERENCIA_2_FECHAS( fch_anterior, fch_actual);       
         ELSIF  p_meses = 0 THEN
            IF p_dias < 0 THEN          
               RETURN DIFERENCIA_2_FECHAS( fch_anterior, fch_actual);                 
            END IF;
         ELSE
              IF p_dias < 0 THEN
                 p_meses := p_meses - 1;
                 p_dias := 29 + p_dias;
              END IF;
         END IF;        
     ELSE       
        IF  p_meses < 0 THEN       
            p_anios  := p_anios -1;
            p_meses := p_meses + 12;
                  IF p_dias < 0 THEN
                       p_meses := p_meses - 1;
                     p_dias := 29 + p_dias;
                  END IF;                 
        ELSIF  p_meses = 0 THEN
              IF p_dias < 0 THEN
                 p_anios := p_anios -1;
                 p_meses := 11;
                 p_dias := 29 + p_dias;
              END IF;
        ELSE
          IF p_dias < 0 THEN
             p_meses := p_meses - 1;
             p_dias := 29 + p_dias;
          END IF;
        END IF;
     END IF;

     RETURN CAST( (LPAD(TO_CHAR(p_anios), 3 , '0') || '.' || LPAD(TO_CHAR(p_meses), 2 , '0') || LPAD(TO_CHAR(ABS(p_dias)), 2 , '0')) AS NUMBER) ;

  END DIFERENCIA_2_FECHAS;
```

Comment: Al momento de probar el codigo me genera un error el la palabra FROM de (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fch_actual)  - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fch_anterior));

Comment: cual es el error?

Comment: este es un link donde encuentras documentación de esta función 

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php

Answer (score 0):

en realidad no entendí muy bien lo que querías. Si lo que quieres es saber la cantidad de días, meses y años creo que esto te puede servir.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DIFERENCIA_FECHAS (
    FECHA_ANTIGUA DATE,
    FECHA_RECIENTE DATE
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    V_DIAS NUMBER(3);
    V_MESES NUMBER(3);
    V_ANNIOS NUMBER(5);

BEGIN
    V_DIAS := TRUNC(FECHA_RECIENTE) - TRUNC(FECHA_ANTIGUA);
    V_MESES := MONTHS_BETWEEN(FECHA_RECIENTE,FECHA_ANTIGUA);
    V_ANNIOS := EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FECHA_RECIENTE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FECHA_ANTIGUA);

    RETURN TO_CHAR('DIAS: ' + V_DIAS + ', MESES: ' + V_MESES + ', AÑOS: ' + V_ANNIOS);
END;
```

Ahora la funcion `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` te permite calcular los meses entre dos fecha sin realizar mayor esfuerzo con adaptar los días a meses.

Te daba negativo porque lo tenias al revés, estabas restando a la fecha antigua el valor de la fecha actual.

El año, bueno, con `EXTRACT()` puedes sacarlo, restando el resultado de la fecha antigua a la fecha actual.
Ojo que al usar `EXTRACT()` para calcular la cantidad de dias o meses, no te va a servir sin hacer un calculo mas complejo, esto se debe a que `EXTRACT(DAY FROM ...)` te va a sacar, por ejemplo, el 3 de 03/04/19 y al restarlo con el 2 del 02/08/18 te va a resultar 1.

Espero te ayude de algo. Saludos.